# Is it possible to make python print a specified string if it get an error?

Tags: python

What I mean is, if for example I get an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "score_keeper-test.py", line 106, in <module>
    app = program()
  File "score_keeper-test.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.label1.set_text(team1_name)
TypeError: Gtk.Label.set_text() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

Is there any way to make python print something like "You MUST enter a name in the TWO boxes" instead of the error above?

Comment: You need exception handling or simply: if-else check for value is None or not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Pythonic idiom is [*EAFP*](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp): easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. In this case:

```
try:
    self.label1.set_text(team1_name)
except TypeError:
    print "You MUST enter a name in the TWO boxes"
```

Note how I explicitly catch `TypeError`. This is recommended by [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (*essential* reading for any Python programmer):

> When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare `except:` clause.

An alternative (not-recommended) approach would be:

```
if team1_name:
    self.label1.set_text(team1_name)
else:
    print "You MUST enter a name in the TWO boxes"
```

...which is an example of [*LBYL*](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl): Look before you leap. This style can leave your code littered in `if`-statements.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reasons behind each and why one should choose one over the other.

Comment: Good points, but I might suggest one qualification. In performance-critical situations, you want to avoid `try-except` stanzas in which the `except` block is the common path. Sometimes the best way to remedy that undesirable (slow) outcome is with good-old `if-else`. David Beazley discusses this in *Python Essential Reference*.

Answer (score 2):

```
if value:
   #Do stuff
else:
   print "You MUST enter a name in the TWO boxes"
```

Now, here, if the `value` is `None`, it will print the string - "You MUST enter a name in the TWO boxes"